# WPF Slider problems

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

I have seen this behaviour, on an old win32 app, where when you hold down the mouse at some position on the slider track (other than on the thumb), the thumb moves to that position.

In WPF what seems to be happening is the thumb moves a distance defined either by SmallChange or LargeChange. If you keep holding, it moves by SmallChange/LargeChange again after some time as defined by the Delay property.

Now I want to get the old behaviour? So if the thumb is at 2 and I press the mouse down near 10 I want it to jump to 10. Whats the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Slider.IsMoveToPointEnabled

I dont know how many times I went through all the properties before finding it.