# Change slider position on custom place

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

I have Slider which show changing time of playing song. Slider show changing tick ok, but I want click on whatever place on Slider that value change then.

But now when I click that, value change only on 1 second. How could I change this behavior?

Comment: Hi netmajor, could you clarify your question a little? Do you want the slider button to jump to the specific place on the bar when you click? Or is your problem that you can only move the slider in discrete tick intervals by *dragging* the button?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make sure the slider can be moved to any point (not just on the predefined ticks), set `IsSnapToTickEnabled` to false:

```
<Slider IsSnapToTickEnabled="False" />
```

But if you are trying to make the slider jump to the point you click at on the slider track, use the [solution outlined in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612412/wpf-slider-problems/613570#613570) and allow move-to-point behaviour:

```
<Slider IsMoveToPointEnabled="True" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to adjust the resolution of your slider. Do this by adjusting the `Minimum` and `Maximum` values, such that you get a better range.